# d3js brush how to get values for selection

Tags: d3.js, brush

I am having date stackedbar chart in d3js v4 and I want to add function for brush selection.

I can't get x-values from d3.event.selection. It shows  `TypeError: x.invert is not a function` error. Why? I am using brush code from [example](https://bl.ocks.org/SpaceActuary/2f004899ea1b2bd78d6f1dbb2febf771). Do I miss any special library?

Here is part of my code. The bottom part is the most important one :D:

```
 var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
        var z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#d53e4f', '#fc8d59', '#fee08b', '#ffffbf', '#e6f598', '#99d594', '#3288bd']);

        x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return parseDate(d.time);
        }));

        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.sum;
        })]);
        z.domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.keys;
        }));


   var stack = d3.stack()
            .keys(keys)
            .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
            .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

        var layers = stack(data);

        var layer = g.selectAll(".layer")
            .data(layers)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "layer");

         layer.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) {
                return d;
            })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr('class', 'barStacked')
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return x(parseDate(d.data.time));
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return y(d[1]);
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
                return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
            })
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

     g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 5) + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
            .call(yAxis);


       g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "brush")
            .call(d3.brushX()
                .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
                .on("end", brushended));

        function brushended() {
          if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return; // Only transition after input.
          if (!d3.event.selection) return; // Ignore empty selections.
            var extent = d3.event.selection;
             console.log(x.domain([ x.invert(extent[0]), x.invert(extent[1]) 
    ]));

        }
    }
```

Comment: The error is because d3.scaleBand does not have an invert method, this method is found in d3's continuous scales, such as in the linked example.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew has said, [scaleBand](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleBand) doesn't have an invert method. The example in the link is a continuous (time) scale which does have an invert method ([here](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_invert)).

If your scaleBand is effectively a representing a continuous time scale, one solution would be to create an additional scale (a scaleTime) that has the same range as your scale 'x', and then use the invert method of this. When specifying the domain, you'll need to be careful to factor in the bandwidth and padding, to make it equivalent to 'x' though.